# Verify the identity $\frac{\tan(a+b)}{\tan(a-b)}$ = $\frac{\sin(a)\cos(a)+\sin(b)\cos(b)}{\sin(a)\cos(a)-\sin(b)\cos(b)}$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been asked to verify the following identity but I don't know how to do it.

$$\frac{\tan(a+b)}{\tan(a-b)} = \frac{\sin(a)\cos(a)+\sin(b)\cos(b)}{\sin(a)\cos(a)-\sin(b)\cos(b)}$$

When I try I get

$$\frac{\tan(a+b)}{\tan(a-b)} = \frac{\dfrac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos(a+b)}}{\dfrac{\sin(a-b)}{\cos(a-b)}} = \frac{\dfrac{\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)}}{\dfrac{\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)}}$$  But I don't know really where to go from here.

Comment: Have u tried multiply directly? It should work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

Use $$2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$$

Then [Prosthaphaeresis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas  $$\sin C-\sin D=?\text{ and }\sin C+\sin D=?$$

Answer (score 3):

This can be somewhat lengthy and can take more time but give it a try :

[image]

In the  last step you know what you have to apply.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice answer. In future though, please type it up in MathJax (the reason for this is, among other things, accessibility)

Answer (score 0):

Use $$\sin{a}\cos{a}+\sin{b}\cos{b}=\frac{1}{2}(\sin2a+\sin2b)=\sin(a+b)\cos(a-b)$$ and
$$\sin{a}\cos{a}-\sin{b}\cos{b}=\frac{1}{2}(\sin2a-\sin2b)=\sin(a-b)\cos(a+b)$$